# Set python indent to 2 spaces in emacs 23?

Tags: emacs, python-mode

I am using emacs 23.1.1 on Ubuntu 10.04. I wish to program in Python with a 2-space indent.  emacs looks to have a default mode for python (python.el?).

I put the following in my .emacs:

```
    ;; Only spaces, no tabs
    (setq indent-tabs-mode nil)

    ;; Always end a file with a newline
    (setq require-final-newline nil)

    ;; Don't know which of these might work
    (setq-default tab-width 2)
    (setq-default python-indent 2)
    (setq-default py-indent-offset 2)
```

When I edit a Python file, it uses a 4-space indent.  When I try C-h v python-indent it says:

```
    python-indent's value is 4
    Local in buffer webpage_cache.py; global value is 2

        This variable is safe as a file local variable if its value
        satisfies the predicate `integerp'.

    Documentation:
    Number of columns for a unit of indentation in Python mode.
    See also `M-x python-guess-indent'

    You can customize this variable.
```

That is, it is 4, not 2. Grr. I tried customizing the variable and saving, still 4. I tried customize-group indent, still 4.

How do I get emacs to pay attention?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Either in you .emacs file or in a file referenced by your .emacs add:

```
(setq-default indent-tabs-mode nil)
(setq-default tab-width 2)
```

You can put in a hook if you want to localize

```
;; Python Hook
(add-hook 'python-mode-hook
          (function (lambda ()
                      (setq indent-tabs-mode nil
                            tab-width 2))))
```

EDIT:  I have found the following the following issues can mess with my settings:

- setting the variable before the library is loaded
- other packages/configs resetting the global variables

For both those issues I have found creating hooks and localizing the variables can help.

Comment: This answer ignores the fact that I already had tab-width 2 in my .emacs, and doesn't explain any of what I was seeing.  Still, my setup works now (don't know why), so I'll accept.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why wrap (lambda ...) in (function ...)? I hadn't seen (function ...) before, and the manual suggests it's not necessary.

Comment: Tyler: Historically, it made a difference. It's no longer necessary, but still a habit for many people. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1852844/emacs-lisp-difference-between-function-lambda-and-lambda for details.

Comment: I have python-indent at 2 and tab-indent at two and I still get an actual indent of 1.  That stuff like this is this finicky in emacs is not at all good.

Answer (score 23):

You can put this into your .emacs file:

```
(add-hook 'python-mode-hook '(lambda () 
 (setq python-indent 2)))
```

The reason why

```
    (setq-default python-indent 2)
```

does not work may because this variable does not exit when .emacs is loaded. (But I am an emacs newbie. I am not sure about my explanation.)

However, [PEP 8 -- Style Guide for Python Code](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) recommends "4 spaces per indentation level" and I find 4 spaces more readable. I actually use this piece of code to force a 4 spaces indentation.

Comment: If you use this code to set the indentation to be the same as the default, are you sure it even works?

Comment: I actually used Vulpecula's fix (my tab indentation was at 8) and it fixed the problem

Answer (score 15):

I just ran into this problem myself, and I think the help for `python-indent` contains a big clue that no one else mentioned:

```
See also `M-x python-guess-indent'
```

If you don't customize `python-guess-indent` by setting it to `nil`, then `python.el` will automatically set `python-indent` for each Python buffer (that contains indented text), making your `python-indent` customization ineffective. (On the other hand, when in Rome...)

In the end, this is what went into my `.emacs` file (ignoring all other custom variables):

```
(custom-set-variables
 '(python-guess-indent nil)
 '(python-indent 2))
```

Comment: For working with existing Python code I needed to set python-guess-indent to nil for things to work the way I wanted it to. For new Python code it wasn't required though. This was a bit confusing until I tried this fix.

Comment: Now in Emacs v26 the python-mode variables have longer names. I ended up with this added to my custom-set-variables. I'm just trying to make it quit guessing and force it to 4. 
'(python-indent-guess-indent-offset nil)
'(python-indent-offset 4)