# Q: Set python indent to 2 spaces in emacs 24?

Tags: emacs, python-mode

I did what it said in [this very helpful thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4251159/set-python-indent-to-2-spaces-in-emacs-23) on how to it in Emacs 23, but it wouldn't work. The indent level keeps on being 4 (the default).

I am on a Mac (MacOS 10.8) using Emacs 24.3.

Answer (score 1):

And the solution turned out to be rather simple. Just include this in your .emacs file

```
(custom-set-variables
 '(python-guess-indent nil)
 '(python-indent-offset 2))
```

So, that is `python-indent-offset` rather than `python-indent`.