# Does (function) serve any purpose in Emacs?

Tags: emacs, lisp, elisp

From the [documentation](http://doc.endlessparentheses.com/Fun/function) of the `function` form:

> Like `quote', but preferred for objects which are functions.
>   In byte compilation, `function' causes its argument to be compiled.
>   `quote' cannot do that.

So one would do `#'(lambda ...)` to enable byte compilation of the lambda form.

On the other hand, [as mentioned in the manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Anonymous-Functions.html), That is no longer necessary.

> The lambda form has one other effect: it tells the Emacs evaluator and byte-compiler that its argument is a function, by using `function` as a subroutine.
>   [...] The following forms are all equivalent:

```
(lambda (x) (* x x)) 
(function (lambda (x) (* x x))) 
#'(lambda (x) (* x x))
```

This renders the function form useless in this case.

Is there any other situation where the function form would have been useful?
Is there any case when its presence is neither unnecessary nor identical to `quote`?

Comment: Note, I'm aware of this related question. http://stackoverflow.com/q/1852844/491532

Comment: Note that `(lambda ...)` was not *always* equivalent to `(function (lambda ...))`, and therefore one answer to your question is "yes, in sufficiently old versions of Emacs".

Comment: It's no longer necessary to do (function (lambda ...)) as opposed to (lambda ...).  But the first quote compares it with `quote`.  You should prefer `(funcall (lambda ...) ...)` or `(funcall (function (lambda ...)) ...)` over `(funcall (quote (lambda ...)) ...)`.  In the former, you get a compiled function;  in the latter you have a literal list.

Comment: @phils: `lambda` was added as a macro that wraps itself in a `function` in 1992 (by Jim Blandy), i.e. for Emacs-19.  So, while the equivalence wasn't true in Emacs-18, that's a rather long time ago.  I still have Emacs-19 working here, but I don't have an Emacs-18 binary.

Comment: Thanks, Stefan. I was sure that "sufficiently old" would prove to be much older than anyone had any practical reason to worry about, but it's always interesting to hear the exact details :) (my comment was just to point out that once upon a time there was indeed a difference).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`#'` (aka `function`) is used internally by `lambda`, since `lambda` is defined as a macro that wraps itself in a `function`.
But other than that, you indeed can write pretty much any Elisp code without using `#'`.  There is one other subtlety, tho: if you write `#'foo` you tell Emacs that you think `foo` is the name of a function, so recent versions of the byte-compiler will then warn if `foo` is not a known function (just like they've been warning about calls to `(foo ...)` for many years already).

As pointed out by @Bruce, the use of `#'foo` instead of `'foo` also makes a real difference for functions defined locally via `cl-flet` or `cl-labels`: in that case `#'foo` refers to the locally defined function, whereas `'foo` will simply refer to the `foo` symbol, which is not actually related to the local function definition and may hence by unbound or bound to another function:

```
(cl-flet ((a () 1)) (list 'a (functionp 'a) #'a))
```

returns

```
(a nil (lambda nil 1))
```

Comment: This commenter on reddit found another difference. Function does lexical binding. http://www.reddit.com/r/emacs/comments/2ddwgc/does_the_function_form_serve_any_actual_purpose/cjooj19

Comment: Indded, Bruce, I had forgotten about that, but the `#'` is needed to refer to local functions defined via `cl-flet` and `cl-labels`.

Comment: -1 This explains the (non-)difference between (lambda ...) and (function (lambda ...)), but it doesn't touch at all on the first part of the question.  In Emacs, you can still do `(funcall (quote (lambda ...)) ...)`, and it's in that context that you won't be compiling the function form as a function, but rather as a list.  It's not that (function (lambda ...)) is preferred over (lambda ...), but that (function (lambda ...)) is preferred over (quote (lambda ...)).

Comment: I don't understand what "first part of the question" you're referring to.  But indeed, there's no preference of `#'(lambda ...)` over just `(lambda ...)`.

Comment: @Stefan, the first quotation in the question says that function is **"Like `quote`, but preferred for objects which are functions. In byte compilation, `function` causes its argument to be compiled. `quote` cannot do that."** The title of the question is **Does (function) serve any purpose in Emacs?** The answer is *yes* (no disagreement there), and it's even used in the expansion of macro `(lambda …)` to `(function (lambda …))`. Because the first quotation from the documentation contrasts it with **quote**, the real issue here is not between `(lambda …)` and `(function (lambda …))`, since…

Comment: …the former expands to the latter, but rather between `(quote (lambda …))` and `(function (lambda …))`.  In Emacs, you can still funcall a list beginning with lambda (e.g., `(funcall '(lambda (x) x) 2) ;=> 2`), but you won't get any compilation.  *That's* where the benefit of `(function …)` (or the shorthand `#'…`) comes in.

Comment: Yes, we all violently agree on this.  I see nowhere in this page where someone argues about "(lambda …) vs (function (lambda …))".

Comment: @Stefan I think I may have been unclear in the comments.  I've tried to make a clearer explanation in [an answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25285974/1281433).  (I've also removed my -1;  I think having the information available in another answer will let others see if sufficiently.)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59299/discussion-between-stefan-and-joshua-taylor).

Answer (score 4):

`lambda` is a macro. It has to be expanded and it is expanded every time. Like this:

```
(lambda (x) x) -> (function (lambda (x) x)) ; #'(lambda (x) x)
```

`function` is a special operator. In fact, it treats `lambda` forms specially, otherwise we would never be able to expand `lambda` macro:

```
(lambda (x) x) ->
  (function (lambda (x) x)) ->
    (function (function (lambda (x) x))) ->
      ...
```

`function` looks at its argument and if it is a `lambda` form, it compiles the function. If its argument is a symbol, then it searches for compiled function associated with the symbol.

So, we see now, that `function` (like `quote`) does not evaluate its argument. It must have special behavior, thus it is a special operator.

Comment: Technically, function doesn't compile anything, it enables the compilation. I asked this question because lambda by itself already enables compilation, and I'm not aware of any case where the compiler actually compiles symbols.

Comment: @Bruce, well, when applied to lambda, `function` returns lexical closure. Compiled it or not is implementation dependent. For example in SBCL [everything is compiled](http://www.sbcl.org/manual/#Compiler_002donly-Implementation). Every closure. As for Emacs Lisp, I really don't know how it works. I used word 'compile' for simplification.

Comment: I see your point. I was referring to emacs lisp, where (lambda) is perfectly identical to (function (lambda)). But I see the value in your answer now.

Comment: @BruceConnor The first quotation in the question is the key to where emacs can work with code that *definitely* won't be compiled.  You can (in Emacs, but not in CL) `(funcall '(lambda (x) x) 2)`, for instance.  Since you can't do that in most Lisps anymore, the difference isn't so marked, but the important difference here is between `(quote (lambda …))` and `(function (lambda …))`, not between `(function (lambda …))` and `(lambda …)` (since the latter just expands to the former).

Answer (score 4):

> So one would do `#'(lambda ...)` to enable byte compilation of the
>   lambda form.
>
> On the other hand, as mentioned in the manual, That is no longer
>   necessary.

It's no longer necessary for the *programmer* to write **(function (lambda …))** (or the shorthand **#'(lambda …)**, because **(lambda …)** expands to **(function (lambda …))**.  Other answers have explained that very well.  You first cite the documentation for function:

> From the documentation of the function form:
>
> > Like `quote`, but preferred for objects which are functions. In byte
> >     compilation, `function` causes its argument to be compiled. `quote`
> >     cannot do that.

Thus, the documentation of **function** isn't addressing the difference between

- `(function (lambda …))` and
- `(lambda …)`,

but rather between

- `(quote (lambda …))` and
- `(function (lambda …))`.

In most modern Lisps (Common Lisp, Scheme, etc.), the form **(quote (lambda …))**, or simply **'(lambda …))** is just a *list*, and it's not something that can be invoked.  E.g., in SBCL:

```
* (funcall '(lambda () 42))
; debugger invoked on a TYPE-ERROR in thread #<THREAD "initial thread" RUNNING {1002978E71}>:
;  The value (LAMBDA () 42) is not of type (OR FUNCTION SYMBOL).
```

However, in Emacs Lisp, you *can* invoke a list:

```
(funcall '(lambda () 42))
;=> 42
```

In asking whether **function** serves any purpose, we have to ask "what can we do without it," or "what alternative is there?"  We can't respond that that "we would just write  **(lambda …)**," because, as others have pointed out, that just expands to **(function (lambda …))**.  If we don't have **function**, we can still use **quote**.  We could still write a **lambda** macro that expands to **(quote (lambda …))**, and thus write **(funcall (lambda …))**, and the code would look the same.  The question is, "what's the difference?"  The difference is that in a **quote**-based version, we're passing literal lists around, and these can't get compiled to functions because we still have to be able to do list-like things with them (e.g., take their **car** and **cdr**).  *This* is where **function** is useful, whether we write it ourselves, or depend on a macro to use it in an expansion.  It gives a way of writing *function objects* instead of *lists*.

Comment: Indeed.  This is discussed also at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16801396/when-should-emacs-function-syntax-be-used/16802304#16802304

Comment: @Stefan Now that's a nice answer that discusses this issue.  I'll gladly +1 your answer here if you touch on that point.  I think it's the important part in answering whether "(function) serve any purpose in Emacs?"  If you couldn't funcall a list, then **(lambda …)** would already have to be something akin to **(function (lambda …))**.  It's only really needed (aside from local functions, a la flet/labels) because there's an alternative with quote.